# Espresso android facebook login

Tags: android, facebook, testing, authentication, android-espresso

I want to be able to test the facebook login function on my app. I have been searching for a way to test android facebook login to my app with espresso. So far everything has came up dry. My main problem is after I click the login button, login credentials pop up and I am not sure how to access their elements or id to input the correct credentials to login.

Comment: are you trying for facebook native app or webview ?

Comment: facebook native app

Answer (score 1):

You should use `uiautomator` for this purpose. It is easy to combine `uiautomator` with `espresso`. See [here](https://testyour.app/espresso-uiautomator).